# list of selectable units for journalctl

Tags: grep, systemd

In a CentOS 7 server, I want to get the list of selectable units for which `journalctl` can produce logs.  How can I change the following code to accomplish this?

```
journalctl --output=json-pretty | grep -f UNIT | sort -u
```

In the CentOS 7 terminal, the above code produces `grep: UNIT: No such file or directory`.

**EDIT:**

The following java program is terminating without printing any output from the desired grep.  How can I change things so that the java program works in addition to the terminal version?

```
    String s;
    Process p;
    String[] cmd = {"journalctl --output=json-pretty ","grep UNIT ","sort -u"};
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("line: " + s);
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue()+", "+p.getErrorStream());
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((s = br2.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("error line: " + s);
        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: "but not when i call it from the a java program" and the Java program?

Comment: There is a typo in that, it should be `grep -F`

Comment: @don_crissti As you wish.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`journalctl` can display logs for all units - whether these units write to the log is a different matter.

To list all available units and therefore all available for `journalctl` to use:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --all
```

---

As to your java code, in order to make pipes work with [`Runtime.exec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5928225/1601027) you could either put the command in a script and invoke the script or use a string array, something like:

```
String[] cmd = {"sh", "-c", "command1 | command2 | command3"};
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

or:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "command1 | command2 | command3"});
```

Comment: `list-unit-files` doesn't show instantiated units and transient units.

Answer (score 32):

[`man journalctl`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html#-F) says:

> -F, --field= Print all possible data values the specified field can take in all entries of the journal.

So, you can run:

```
journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT
```

to get the list of selectable units for which `journalctl` can produce logs

(by default, only root and users who are members of a few special groups are granted access to the system journal and the journals of other users. Members of the groups `systemd-journal`, `adm`, and `wheel` can read all journal files. )

Comment: You must be a superuser to run that command.  So make it `sudo journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT`.  But otherwise thank you and +1 for adding insight.

Comment: Actually if you don't `sudo` you can use `journalctl` but you only get a tiny list of units that are directly related to your user's session.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as `systemd 219` does not support the arguments `list-unit-files --all` provided in the currently accepted answer.

Comment: list-unit-files just shows the unit files.  You can get a similar list by just typing "systemctl" with no arguments. Most of them do not support journald so that command is of no use.

Comment: Very much seems this is the correct answer. Not clear if `sudo` is needed on some distributions.

`~ journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | wc -l     
 100
 ~ sudo journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | wc -l
 100
 ~ lsb_release -d                               
 Description: Pop!_OS 20.10`

Comment: This by itself is not helpful; there are way too many results; `journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | wc -l` => 93298.  Any many of them are redundant; `journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | sort -u | wc -l` => 39739.  Even if I try to grep it down to services, it's highly redundant: `journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | grep ".service$" | wc -l` => 862, while `journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | grep ".service$" | sort -u | wc -l` => 47.  That last one is close to what I wanted.

Comment: @ShadSterling that sounds like something very specific to your system and having an unusual amount of results. My results with the command only produces 44 results without any grepping. The question you should likely ask is why your system is producing 93298 different log units.

Comment: @Routhinator this may be a difference between distros, right now on my openSUSE Tumbleweed host, `journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | wc -l` ⇒ `32205`, and `journalctl --field _SYSTEMD_UNIT | grep "^session-.*\.scope$" | wc -l` ⇒ `32146`, so almost all are are whatever `session-*.scope` is